# ASP.NET small online store, shopping cart

Tags: asp.net, shopping-cart, google-checkout, cart

Currently I have a site that is using Google Checkout's mini cart system and I like it a lot, however, I'm wondering if there is a more professional way of doing it, while still keeping it simple.

I've looked into an authorize.net account, but I need to find a way to handle the mini shopping cart before heading off to process the order.

**Are there any good open source mini shopping carts that are not linked with a merchant service?**

Comment: nopCommerce may be worth a look

Comment: @Code Poet, thanks for a post.
@AJ, thanks for that, but I've looked into it, and I'm not looking for a store front, just a cart system, basically, the products that are in the store are added dynamically from a folder (photo company), and if you put in the date and location you can see your photo and order it. Its not a standard online store by any measurement.

Comment: sounds like you could build your own very simple system to do this. If all you want is an app to trawl a directory on your computer, iterate through the files and allow them to be previewed then added to a shopping cart, it's only really a trivial matter to write your own checkout process, especially if you're using something like Google Checkout or Paypal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with Google Checkout, just wanted to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Can't close the question, can still answer.

For Asp.Net one of the most popular shopping carts is AspDotNetStorefront. It's not inexpensive, but extensible.

PayflowPro ( run by PayPal ) might be an option you want to consider in the future. It's more professinoal than Paypal, fully skinnable.